# Why do my camera shots have a dark area at the top?

Tags: troubleshooting, repair, equipment-damage, nikon-d5100, shutter

Until a couple of days ago, there was no problem, but now my images have a dark band at the top of them. What could be the reason?

See an example below

Is there anything I can do, or does the camera need to be repaired?

My camera is Nikon D5100. I bought it 3 years ago, so the warranty period is over.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just this once, or all of your photos since a certain point?

Comment: All photos (from today) showing this :(

Comment: Do you use any lens hoods or filters?

Comment: looks like your shutter blinds (or your mirror) are still in the way when the sensor data is being accumulated.

Comment: try locking your mirror up and then taking a picture (assuming that model can do this).

Comment: Are you using flash with a shutter speed faster than 1/200s? (the D5100 cannot do FP/HSS flash).

Comment: @Michael Stum: No, don't use lens hoods or filters.

Comment: @dav1dsm1th: How to do that (locking mirror up)?

Comment: @inkista: Not using flash at all...

Comment: I can see the dark area in view finder as well...

Comment: It looks like you can lock up the mirror by using "live view" to capture an image. But if you are seeing the dark area in the viewfinder, it's not a sticky mirror that's causing you problem - it's something in the image path between your mirror and whatever you are trying to capture...  but I'm at a loss (as the leaves in the aperture mechanism would not produce the shadow you are seeing).

Comment: do you have another lens you could try?

Comment: @dav1dsm1th Yes, got another lens 70-300mm Tamron. Tried that now, getting more dark area :( 

See second image, please.

Comment: Took first image with 18-55mm Nikkor lens (got along with camera).

Comment: Shutter curtain getting stuck I would think.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall but OP says he is seeing the shadow in the viewfinder, which shouldn't be effected by the shutter blinds.  Weird.

Comment: So he does, I missed that comment. It could still be the mirror being out of position, not throwing the image onto the pentaprism properly perhaps? There is pretty much nothing else it could be, it's too straight to be something in the lens I believe.

Comment: I made a wrong comment regarding viewfinder. Thru viewfinder can see full image. At 'live view' seeing the image with darkness. 
Really sorry @dav1dsm1th got confused b/w them :)

Comment: Ah, then it is likely the shutter. It will need servicing.

Comment: If you can take a picture without the lens, and in bulb mode (or long exposure time), you could watch if the mirror flips up all the way, and if the shutter reveals all of the sensor. (Do this where there is as little dust as possible, and out of direct sunlight.)

Comment: Can you put the D5100 in Live view with the lens removed and take a picture looking into the light box of the D5100 with a different camera? And post it here?

Comment: @ElendilTheTall Perhaps post a summary of all of this as an answer?

Comment: Does the severity of the vignetting always change, or can you tell if it's directly related to the shutter speed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mirror is interposed between the viewfinder and the sensor. The shutter is interposed between the mirror and the sensor. The mirror throws the image into the viewfinder, bypassing the sensor, so if you have a clear viewfinder image but live view (or an actual photo) shows a dark band, this suggests the problem is a sticky shutter. You will need to have it serviced.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The shutter is jamming, i.e. not opening/closing fully.

It "probably" will need servicing.

I had this happen recently on holiday, after I dropped it. The shutter went out of alignment, Which I could see with the lens removed.

But with the help of a table knife, and gentle pushing, I was able to free it. It seems to be OK since, but **TRY AT YOUR OWN RISK**. I was lucky.